# No (non-degenerate) open interval in R can be written as the union of infinitely many (non-degenerate) closed disjoint intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to prove the following proposition: no (non-degenerate) open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as the union of infinitely many (non-degenerate) closed disjoint intervals. Is the following correct?

Suppose that $I\triangleq (a,b)$, $a<b$, is some non-degenerate open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $I\triangleq \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[a_{n}, b_{n}]$, where all intervals are pairwise disjoint.

Let $E$ be the set of endpoints $a_{n}, b_{n}$ of all intervals in the above union, including $a$ and $b$. Note that $E\triangleq \mathbb{R} \not  \hspace{1mm}(-\infty, a)\not  \hspace{1mm} (b, +\infty) \not  \hspace{1mm} \bigcup _{n\in \mathbb{N}}(a_{n}, b_{n})$, and that each of these sets are open, so that $E$ is closed. E is also countable, since each interval in the union comprising $I$ contains a rational number.

For a contradiction, we now show that $E$ is perfect.

Consider some arbitrary $x\in E$ and $\delta>0$. We show that the open ball $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ contains a point $x'\in E$ different from $x$.

Note that since $x\in I$ and $I$ is open, $I\cap(x-\delta, x), I\cap (x, x+\delta) \neq \phi$. Thus there exist $k,m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $[a_{k}, b_{k}]\cap (x-\delta, x), [a_{m}, b_{m}]\cap(x, x+\delta)\neq\phi$.

Suppose first that $x=a_{n}$ for some $n$. Note that $x\notin[a_{k}, b_{k}]$, since if $x\in (a_{k}, b_{k}]$, then $[a_{n}, b_{n}]$ and $[a_{k}, b_{k}]$ would not be disjoint. If $x=a_{k}$, then $[a_{k}, b_{k}]\cap (x-\delta, x) = \phi$, a contradiction. Also, we must have that $x>b_{k}$, since if $x<a_{k}$, then again $[a_{k}, b_{k}]\cap (x-\delta, x) = \phi$, a contradiction. So then we have that $x>b_{k}$ and $[a_{k}, b_{k}]\cap (x-\delta, x) \neq \phi$. Thus it must be that this intersection at a minimum contains $b_{k}$. So then we can set $x'\triangleq b_{k}\in E\cap(x-\delta, x)$.

By similar reasoning, if $x=b_{n}$ for some $n$, then $x\notin [a_{m}, b_{m}]$, $x<a_{m}$, and so we can set $x'\triangleq a_{m}\in E \cap (x, x+\delta)$.

In either case, we found a point $x'\in E \cap (x-\delta, x+\delta)$ different from $x$. Thus $E \subset\mathbb{R}$ is a perfect set. This is a contradiction since $E$ is also countable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This theorem appeared in my textbook prior to any treatment of connectedness. So I presumed I must prove it without recourse to that notion.

Comment: Pretty sure you could attack this simpler by just showing the endpoints couldn't be included.  You'd only have to worry about interior points if we were talking about a closed interval